# Resources for Topological Quantum Field Theory in Condensed Matter?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory

I'm interested in some resources (ideally books) for self-study of topological quantum field theory in condensed matter.  I'd prefer resources that are more mathematically rigorous, so I don't mind books that are aimed more towards mathematicians.

I'm half way through the first year of my PhD in terms of background, but I've also done some pure maths courses (e.g. real analysis, topology, etc).

Comment: Related MathOverflow post with some good resources: https://mathoverflow.net/q/359/69504

Comment: There's unfortunately a pretty wide gulf between the math and physics literature on the subject. There are also many open problems about the connection between gapped phases and TQFTs. From your background it sounds like you might enjoy Freed and Hopkins' papers, but they're still a long way from the physics pov. I'm happy to chat by email btw. Good luck!